# `<returns>` tag in Intellisense in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, xml-documentation

I use Visual Studio (currently 2017 Prof.) + Resharper.
XmlDocs (`\\\<summary> blah </summary>`) are great, and Intellisense will display it to you.
It picks up the `summary` tag, and any `param` tags, if you get the cursor in the right place.

But the `returns` tag is often very useful, especially for Framework Library functions. e.g. reminder of which way around the return value of `int.TryParse()` works, etc.

I can't see any way to access that information from Visual Studio / Intellisense?

Is it accessible? Or does it only turn up in the MSDN docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ctrl + Shift + F1`, aka "Resharper QuickDoc" displays all of the XML documentation that information.

You can modify that shortcut, if desired. Action code is `ReSharper.ReSharper_QuickDoc`.

---

Demonstration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I can't see any way to access that information from Visual Studio /
>   Intellisense?
>
> Is it accessible? Or does it only turn up in the MSDN docs?

So far, Microsoft has not added any Intellisense for the `<Returns>` tag. Nevertheless,`<summary>`and `<param>` do.

**Ideally**, the `<Returns>` tag should have the same effect as `<summary>` tag. But in fact, the info written in the `<Returns>` tag has no effect to show up in any areas and just is a description in the MSDN Docs.  And the feature you want has been proposed by many people,seen [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/31618). So this is a known and discussed problem.

**Therefore**, in order to give feedback to Microsoft as soon as possible, I raised this issue on the DC Forum again. The link is [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/871867/intellisense-for-tag-does-not-work-in-vs2017.html).

You can vote this issue and if l do not describe it in detail,you can add any detailed comments below. Anyone including us who faced the same issue or are interested in this problem will vote it so that it will raise Microsoft's attention as soon as possible.

**In addition**, maybe this is a long process. Actually,[the paid resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which an extension for Visual Studio supports this feature. You can use it for free for 30 days. 
Besides, you can refer to [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Cleanup__Usage_Scenarios__Reformatting_XML.html).

Hope it could help you.

Comment: I think that you're asserting that `<returns>` tags *are* picked up in VS 2015, and in VS2019? Could you expand your answer with screenshots to demonstrate this, to show where the info **ought** to be appearing?